# Raster calculator ArcGIS, high precision floating point operation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator, floating-point

I need to preform a transformation on a DTM, in order to use it as a variable in a multiple regression equation (the variables, including elevation data have been box-cox transformed).

A part of the transformation looks like this:

```
("dtm"**3.813499755859380) - 1
```

The first part, the power (**, or ^) transformation results in a raster image with values I expect to see, min and max values of this raster are: `1.596767423145407e-013 and 2.391312495242381e-011`.

However, when I want to subtract 1, ArcGis rounds all my values to -1.

How can I suppress this rounding? In Matlab, this would result in something close to `-0.9999999......98000` for example, but it doesn't round it to -1. I need this information to continue my tranformation of the DTM.

Pixel type and depth for this raster are: floating point and 32 Bit.

Comment: It rounds result to 1 because it is essentially 1

Comment: I did the analysis in Matlab, where it did work.  Indeed it is practically 1, but for the transformation, I need the information behind all the -0.9999999...'s. I guess there will be some work-around in python itself, but for the Raster Calculator in ArcGis I don't think it will be possible indeed.